# Why do I get this error for the "describe table" function in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, cmd

So i'm doing the simplest query in the world in the cmd:

```
mysql> use adgregator;
Database changed
mysql> describe adgregator
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'adgregator.adgregator' doesn't exist;
```

I don't get it, what's his problem???

Comment: The table `adgregator.adgregator` doesn't exist.  I think the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: The `describe` command expects a _table name_ as argument, not a database holding tables.

Comment: yes, i DO have a table called adgregator, i mean Im on it, it is there and live;

Comment: i didnt ask it to describe adgregator.adgregator, but i did ask it to describe adgregator....

Comment: oh, yeah, got it....you are right @arkascha :) that is a database, not a table :)

Comment: Can you try SHOW TABLES to see list of tables in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use **desc** or **describe** command to see the tables of a database. But you can use this command to see the structure of a particular table.

If you want to see the tables of the database

You can use this commands :

```
use database_name;
show tables;
```

To see the structure of the particular table

You can use this command :

```
desc table_name;
or
describe table_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
describe adgregator.adgregator
```

maybe?

The problem seems to be the compiler takes as parameter the database with name adgregator, not the table.

Comment: The error message clearly indicates there is no ambiguity, it's not going to change anything being explicit.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, i just realized i was just asking  MySQL the wrong question, like describing a database instead of a table.

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Comment: yes, i did :)show full tables from adgregator and after that describe name_table;